# WPF Datagrid Row Context Menu - Disable Menu Item

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, contextmenu, wpfdatagrid

Hi There I am beginner programmer and new to WPF and have a simple question, but I have spent quite some time searching it a could not figure it out, so I hope you guys will help me.
All I want is to disable menu item in a context menu in my Datagrid.
for example: if more than one rows selected in Datagrid , disable a context menu item "Properties"

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <ContextMenu  x:Key="DataRowContextMenu">
            <MenuItem x:Name="RowContMenuProp"  Header="Properties">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Resources/proporties.ico" Height="16" Width="16" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <Separator Margin="0"  />
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy" >
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Resources/copy.ico" Height="16" Width="16" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove from list" Click="MenuItem_Click_1" >
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Resources/cut.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove from project" Click="MenuItem_Click_2" >
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Resources/remove.ico" Height="16" Width="16" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGrid.RowStyle >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DataRowContextMenu}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

-- disable Context menu item

```
Private Sub datagrid1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
        If datagrid1.SelectedItems.Count > 1 Then
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to go about it. It is a bit dirty but works.

First create an IValueConverter to say that 1 means enable (true) and the Value Converter may look like this

```
public class OneReturnsTrueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value == 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then save a reference to the DataGrid in your DataGridRow

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DataRowContextMenu}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

And finally bind the SelectedItems count of the grid to the IsEnabled property

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <myConverters:OneReturnsTrueConverter x:Key="OneReturnsTrueConverter"/>
    <ContextMenu  x:Key="DataRowContextMenu">
        <MenuItem x:Name="RowContMenuProp"  Header="Properties"
                  DataContext="{Binding Parent.PlacementTarget.Tag , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SelectedItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource OneReturnsTrueConverter}}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [WPF Command pattern implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). *A command can indicate whether an action is possible by implementing the CanExecute method. A button can subscribe to the CanExecuteChanged event and **be disabled if CanExecute returns false or be enabled if CanExecute returns true**.*

You can easily adapt the code from the MSDN page to your needs.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="RowContMenuProp" Header="Properties"
          Command="local:ApplicationsCmd.ShowProperties"
          CanExecute="ShowPropertiesCanExecute"
          Executed="ShowPropertiesExecuted" >
```

Then in code:

```
Private Sub ShowPropertiesExecuted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
  ...
End Sub

Private Sub ShowPropertiesCanExecute(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)
  e.CanExecute = ...set to True when your condition is met
End Sub
```